# Set up JWT Policies with Claims in .NET Core 3.1?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, jwt

I am trying to set up my project with authorization middle ware using `JWT`.

Here is a scenario for example

I have 3 modules

1. Analytics

   - Search
   - View
   - Save
2. Search

   - Search
   - View
   - Save
3. Admin

   - Only admins

---

From my understanding based on multiple blogs I have to set up middle ware With `Policy` that will represent my functionality `Analytics`, `Search`, `Admin`. Then I decorate Controller with `[Authorize(Policy="Analytics")]` and JWT will authorize against that `Analytics` Policy.

Question:

If My policy has multiple functions like `Search = 1`, `View = 2`, `Save = 3`, where `Save` has access to both `View` and `Search` how do I configure claim for that policy and pass information into `Authorize` attribute?

```
 services.AddAuthorization((options) =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("Analytics", policy =>
                {
                    policy.AuthenticationSchemes.Add(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
                    ???
                    ???
                    ???
                });
            });
```

```
[Authorize(Policy = "Analytics")]
```

Comment: So you want to specify access at the module level, or you need to control access at the function level of each module?  Using [Authorize(Policy = "Analytics")] implies it's all of nothing access to the Analytics module.

Comment: @BryanLewis If possible Id like to specify configuration for authorization at middle ware level. 
So, after that on controller action I could do something like this `Authorize(Policy="Analytics", SomethingElse="Search")`
This action will have access to `Analytics` module and with only Search function, but if user has `Save` function then he/she should be able to access `Search` and `View`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple options I think. If you want to use policies and you only need to control access per module, then you would create 3 policies and add one or more claims to a given user's token to check against. Obviously the names of the policies and claims is up to you:

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>  
{  
    options.AddPolicy("Analytics", policy => policy.RequireClaim("AllowAnalytics"));  
    options.AddPolicy("Search", policy => policy.RequireClaim("AllowSearch")); 
    options.AddPolicy("Admin", policy => policy.RequireClaim("AllowAdmin"));  
});
```

Controller would have the auth attribute as you previously specified:

```
[Authorize(Policy = "Analytics")]
```

And you would have to add one of more claims (AllowAnalytics, AllowSearch, AllowAdmin) to the user's JWT token when it was issued.  This method is pretty straight forward, but doesn't scale well.  For just three areas, it fine, but if you have a lot more modules or need to have more fine-grain control, it doesn't do well.

If your users can be neatly classified into roles and action permissions can be easily mapped to those roles, then you are better off using that option.  This can be done either with the built in ASP.Net identity roles ([Authorize(Roles = "Analytics,Admin")]) or just adding a "role" claim to the JWT token and use the RequireClaim policy like the above example.

Lastly, if you have more complex requirements, like any user can have an arbitrary combination of permissions (User A need Analytics-View and Search-Search but nothing else), then you probably want to go with a more sophisticated solution that involves assigning specific access permissions to every controller action and storing a user's combination of access in a DB or something.  Check out John P Smith's posts about his solution and his code on GitHub, it's pretty good:

- https://www.thereformedprogrammer.net/a-better-way-to-handle-asp-net-core-authorization-six-months-on/
- https://github.com/JonPSmith/PermissionsOnlyApp

Comment: Thank you for detailed explanation and your time to provide this. What are your thoughts on implementing your own custom `Authorize` Attribute?

Comment: No problem.  If you think this answer is sufficient, please mark it as answered.

Comment: Of course. Btw what are your thoughts on an idea of writing custom `Authorize` attribute?