# ASP.NET Core Authorize attribute with both Policy and Roles

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I have an ASP.NET Core 6.0 project and I use 2 authentication schemes.

One of the authencation schemes is, as default "**JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme**"

and this works only for Role-based auth.

another one is "**Custom**"

"Custom" is used only for Policy-based auth.

```
.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
   options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
   options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
   options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
   .....
}
.AddJwtBearer("Custom", options =>
{
    .....
});
```

And after that I added some scopes to "Custom" policy.

I would like to reach the controller with;

**[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes ="Custom",Policy = "RandomPolicyName")]**

***OR***

**[Authorize(Roles="User")]**

***I know I cannot use both on the same controller, it cannot work because it has to pass both authorize attributes. So how can I do that ??***

Comment: Hi @serhatyt, Have you tried `[Authorize(Policy = "RandomPolicyName", Roles = "User")]`? How do you implements policy based? The common way should be like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59745000/11398810). Pls share more code for how do you implements jwt.

Comment: [Authorize(Policy = "RandomPolicyName", Roles = "User")] is not useful for my question. I would like to use Authorize for both "Custom" scheme and "JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme" seperately. And the controller will accept the request if one of them passes not both of them.

Comment: So how do you implements the two authorization? Pls share more detailed code.

Comment: When you use - [Authorize(AuthenticationScheme="JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme",Roles = "RoleName")]  and - [Authorize(AuthenticationScheme="Custom",Policy="PolicyName")] together on a controller. It has to pass both Authorize attributes. But I would like it to pass if one of them is accepted, not both of them...

Comment: @serhatyt did you solve this? I'm trying to do something similar with AzureAD auth (roles) and IdentityServer (policy). My app is configured to use either for authentication  and I have [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme + ", AzureAdBearer")] at the top of my controller. This works but the issue is how to allow either auth method access to a method that requires the admin role/policy (depending on auth type)

Comment: I think both cannot be used together on top of a controller, so it's better to use custom auth attribute to control both with OR seperately. If any other idea or someone who has got a different perspective, would be great ! :)  @esp

Answer (score 1):

I solved this. This works for me, if you see any problem or have any other idea, then share with us :)

- ***Authorize attribute***

  ```
  public class AuthorizeMultiplePolicyAttribute : TypeFilterAttribute
  {
     public AuthorizeMultiplePolicyAttribute(string policies, bool IsAll) : base(typeof(AuthorizeMultiplePolicyFilter))
     {
         Arguments = new object[] { policies, IsAll };
     }
  }
  ```
- ***Policy Filter***

  ```
  public class AuthorizeMultiplePolicyFilter : IAsyncAuthorizationFilter
  {
      private readonly IAuthorizationService _authorization;
      public string _policies { get; private set; }
      public bool _isAll { get; set; }
      public AuthorizeMultiplePolicyFilter(string policies, bool IsAll, IAuthorizationService authorization)
      {
          _policies = policies;
          _authorization = authorization;
          _isAll = IsAll;
      }

      public async Task OnAuthorizationAsync(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
      {
          var policys = _policies.Split(";").ToList();
          if (_isAll)
          {
              foreach (var policy in policys)
              {
                  var authorized = await _authorization.AuthorizeAsync(context.HttpContext.User, policy);
                  if (!authorized.Succeeded)
                  {
                      context.Result = new ForbidResult();
                      return;
                  }
              }
          }
          else
          {
              foreach (var policy in policys)
              {
                  var authorized = await _authorization.AuthorizeAsync(context.HttpContext.User, policy);
                  if (authorized.Succeeded)
                  {
                      return;
                  }
              }
              context.Result = new ForbidResult();
              return;
          }
      }
  }
  ```
- ***Adding policies***

  ```
  services.AddAuthorization(options =>
  {

      options.AddPolicy("CatalogReadOrWrite", policy =>
      {
            policy.AddAuthenticationSchemes(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
            policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
            policy.RequireAssertion(context => context.User.HasClaim(c =>
                (c.Type == "scope" && (c.Value == "catalog_writepermission" || c.Value == "catalog_readpermission"))
            ));
      });


      options.AddPolicy("CatalogReadUser", policy =>
      {
            policy.AddAuthenticationSchemes(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
            policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
            policy.RequireAssertion(context => context.User.HasClaim(c =>
                (
                  ((c.Type == "role" || c.Type == ClaimTypes.Role || c.Type == "Roles") && (c.Value == "User.Admin" || c.Value == "User.Normal"))
                )
            ));
        });
    });
  }
  ```
- Controller part
- false parameter means if one of policies passes, then authorize

  ```
    [AuthorizeMultiplePolicy("CatalogWrite;CatalogReadOrWrite", false)]
    public async Task<IActionResult> BlaBlaAsync([FromBody] BlaBla model)
    {

    }
  ```
- true parameter means if all of policies passes, then authorize

  ```
    [AuthorizeMultiplePolicy("CatalogWrite;CatalogReadOrWrite", true)]
    public async Task<IActionResult> BlaBlaAsync([FromBody] BlaBla model)
    {

    }
  ```